# using or with .isin() on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to use .isin() on two columns to filter out certain rows.

df =

```
amount    currency1    currency2
50        GBP          nan
47        nan          USD
30        nan          GBP
60        EUR          nan
57        nan          EUR
```

If currency1 is populated with a value then currency2 will not be and vice versa. i want to use isin() to only pick out GBP and USD. i tried using:

```
df = df.loc[df['currency1'].isin(['GBP','USD'])]
```

but then the rows which have GBP or USD in currency2 are taken out of the dataframe so I'd like to do something where it looks for GBP and USD in both columns using maybe an or statement so the dataframe would look like:

```
amount    currency1     currency2
50        GBP           nan
47        nan           USD
30        nan           GBP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df.apply(lambda x:x.isin(['GBP','USD'])).any(1)]

amount currency1 currency2
0      50       GBP       NaN
1      47       NaN       USD
2      30       NaN       GBP
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), which can reduce a row or column of booleans to a single boolean value. Use `axis=1` for row-wise in this case.

```
cols = ['currency1', 'currency2']  # columns to search
currencies = ['GBP', 'USD']  # currencies to search for
df[df[cols].isin(currencies).any(axis=1)]
```

Results:

```
   amount currency1 currency2
0      50       GBP       NaN
1      47       NaN       USD
2      30       NaN       GBP
```